# which phtml file is use for New Order Confirmation Template for Guest/Seller?

Tags: sales-order, email-templates, phtml, order-email, magento-2.1.3

i have created and implemented the code to call product thumbnail and product url for "New Order Confirmation Template" thats is use for customers.my code is below

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
$imagewidth=30;
$imageheight=30;
//$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();

    <div class="product-name"><a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></div>
    <div class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU'); ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></div>
    <div class="sku"><a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <img src="<?= $image_url?>"></a></div>
```

This is my code which iam using in module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order in default.html. now this template get called in module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email
items.phtml to call default.phtml contents.

now my query is when i order something this customized mail along with product thumbnail and product url is going to customers but its not going to seller.

now what i have done is create an email template via sales configuration and callingthe same items.phtml block as below

```
Thank you{{config path="trans_email/ident_custom1/name"}} for your order.

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" order=$order name="order_sms" template="module_sales::items.phtml" area="frontend"}}
```

when iam seeing my customized mail iam getting only 
        Thank youCustom 1 for your order. and the block which i have mentioned at top is not reflecting. what is the issue and can please any body tell me what default email template is use to send out to new guest so that i can customize it accordingly confused.

Comment: so i want to add product thumbnail and product url in order_new_guest.html. how to achieve that sir? earlier you have told me about adding same coding in default.phtml and it worked but only for customer. how to add same thing in order_new_guest.html ?so that product thumbnail and product url is visible to seller also

Answer (score 0):

This is path of email template `magento-slaes/view/frontend/email/order_new_guest.html`

the difference between the layout handles
**order_new_guest**

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

**order_new**

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

Now adding the are in gues template and then check **area="frontend"**

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

Comment: so i want to add product url & product thumbail in that so that seller can see the same.how to ahieve this sir?ealier i have done in default.phtml and it worked but how to achieve the same using html file?
i want to show same product thumbnail and product url in the email template goes to seller

Comment: @YogeshRaghav i added the possible solution for that

Comment: where i suppose to add this code sir? in email-template content or directly in order_new_guest.html nad where to place it sir?

Comment: @YogeshRaghav yes change in the template html file and check the output

Comment: sir i have changed the template as u said but seller is not getting the same email.product link and images are missing in that email. i have registered as seller ,assigned product and tried my self but as a customer i got email along with product link and images but when i logged in my emiam as a seller iam not getting mail along with images and product url. where is the issue sir?

Comment: the content of mail starts from "Yogesh,

I would like to inform you that a order has been sold from the store. You can check the status of your order by logging into your account."

Comment: @YogeshRaghav you want to send the custom email?

Comment: sir i want to send the same email which goes to customer and it should go to seller.can you tell me which template is going to seller by seeing its first lining "Yogesh, I would like to inform you that a order has been sold f">--in which template file it is using...thanonly i could change settings

Comment: @YogeshRaghav sorry can't help you their have limited knowledge of m2.

Comment: sir u will get idea from this what i mean to say.when i order a product .
from customer view iam getting this email: http://prntscr.com/ecsh13

For seller perpective iam getting this email: http://prntscr.com/ecshl2

u can see difference that iam not getting product thumbnail and link in seller email.now i hope u can assist sir

Comment: @YogeshRaghav are you using the third party extension or you are talking about admin email?

Comment: admin email sir. no third part extension...when i order product and than default email that goes both to customer and seller.iam not talking about any third part extension

Comment: @YogeshRaghav did you add this text `ogesh, I would like to inform you that a order has been sold f` and from where?

Comment: no sir i didnt add it its default email that goes to seller after order confirmation..i registered as seller "Yogesh" mail:yogeshraghav3043@gmail.com and ordered item as customer: yogeshhitman47@gmail.com..so as a seeler iam getting this email by default. i havent added anything

Comment: the subject line of email is:

Admin              Order Placed Notification To Seller

Comment: @YogeshRaghav magento use same email for both customer and admin

Comment: but still seller is getting different email sir.iam trying the method u suggested..testing and let you inform

Comment: you can check it urself sir. this is our site . http://111.118.214.83
u register as customer and i will make u seller and assign a product so that you can chekc from your end

Comment: @YogeshRaghav i am trying to tell you this is not default magento working there is marketplace extension in that kindly check for module in `app/code` folder

Comment: There is a Webkul folder in it

Comment: @YogeshRaghav they have template folder check their for email template and edit their for seller notification email

Comment: yes sir template which is using is order_place.html as i can see.but how can i add product thumbnail and product url to it..there is a html file order_place.html having content  {{trans "I would like to inform you that a order has been sold from the store."}}

Comment: @YogeshRaghav share their template file so i can check what they are doing paste template file.

Comment: sir this is the path /app/code/Webkul/Marketplace <-this is the folder responsible for that email.iam sharing u this folder in archive format
here it is:https://www.mediafire.com/?cw55rr7repj3hzx

Comment: iam not sure for which exact template is in use so iam sending u the folder instead https://www.mediafire.com/?cw55rr7repj3hzx

Comment: go to my profile and send on email i will check it later

Comment: i have sent u an email along with link to download the folder from my email: yogeshraghav3043@gmail.com 
kindly do update with solutions when its done sir.i need to present it on monday
thanks in advance

Comment: sir can u please explain how to add the code and where?i have figured out the file so what code to enter?